# Why this warning about early response appears?

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

I am using a proxy built with akka-http. I do some checks in the proxy, but if everything is fine, what I do is only change URL on the original request, add a few headers and pass the request to a service. Nothing fancy, the code is simple:

```
    val r = request
      .withUri(target)
      .withHeaders(
        // add a few
      )

    http.singleRequest(r)
```

In the logs I get such warning:

```
2020-12-07 22:53:54,959 [WARN ] akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl [proxy-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] -  Sending an 2xx 'early' response before end of request for http://localhost:8080/blahblahblah received... Note that the connection will be closed after this response. Also, many clients will not read early responses! Consider only issuing this response after the request data has been completely read!
```

It is impossible I send response early, because I wait for the response from the service, and literally create `Future.successfull(value)` as a `Future[HttpResponse]` from proxy.

It could be possible if early response was sent from the service, but it is not. The warning is only on the proxy, not on the target service.

I digged in akka-http sources, and noticed this warning is printed when response is sent and `MessageEnd` was not yet received in `ControllerStage`. `ControllerStage` receives elements from `HttpRequestParser`. In debug I can clearly see that `HttpRequestParser` emits `MessageEnd` element, but it is never received by `ControllerStage`. It stays forever in `HttpRequestParser` buffer and never gets pulled, because `onPull` is not called anymore.

Why is that? What can be cause of such behavior? When is `pull` called on stage which emits elements?

Comment: If I understood well, your `r` val is a `Future[HttpResponse]`. If yes, why don`t you use an `onComplete` in this val? Or maybe the `pipe` pattern if it applies?

Comment: `r` is `HttpRequest`. Problem is already solved, and the cause was this bug in akka-http: https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/2455